# Choosing MYSQL over Mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, relational-database, nosql

From [mongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql#when-to-use-mysql):

> **When would MySQL be a better fit?**
>
> A concrete example would be the booking engine behind a travel
>   reservation system, which also typically involves complex
>   transactions. While the core booking engine might run on MySQL, those
>   parts of the app that engage with users – serving up content,
>   integrating with social networks, managing sessions – would be better
>   placed in MongoDB

Two things i don't understand in this (not even a little) concrete example:

- What kind of queries are complex enough to be better suited for MYSQL
  (a concrete example of such a query be of great help)?
- Where is the line that seperates the "*core booking engine*" from the
  "*parts of the app that engage with users*"?

My concern is not theoretical as we use both MYSQL and MongoDB in our app, and a better understanding of the above would really help us in designing our DB models for future features.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL is ACID compliant (assuming you're using INNODB or similar), MogoDB is not.  Read the MongoDB docs about atomicity here:

[MongoDB Atomicity](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

Think about going to the grocery store checkout, and that the POS system is using MySQL.  What steps might take place in a single transaction?

- Item scanned, price retrieved
- Inventory updated, quantity on hand is subtracted by 1
- Department metrics updated (add dollar amount,    quantity, item
  type, etc)
- Is the item on sale?  Show how much money    the customer saved on
  the receipt
- Customer used a  coupon, make sure    we notify the vendor so we get
  reimbursed
- Send receipt total to    accounting, update month / year / week stats

Now it's time to pay.  OOPS!  Customer left wallet at home, and says he'll come back later.  We've made all these changes to many database tables, now what do we do?  If we were using MySQL and had all these updates in a single transaction, we could just rollback that one transaction and no harm is done.  All changes will be reverted automatically, and in the correct order.

Doing that in a non-transactional database means writing code to backtrack through all those changes, in the correct order.

MongoDB is good for document storage and retrieval.  It wouldn't be my first choice for creating small pieces of a document a little at a time, where you want to store bits and pieces of information in seperate places.

How do we use MongoDB in our grocery store example?  We could use it as part of an inventory system.

Our MySQL inventory could have a schema of things we absolutely MUST have --- SKU, price, department.  We don't necessarily want to clutter it up with things that we don't often need to know, however, by adding columns such as 'Easter_2016_Promotion'.  In MongoDB, since we don't have a schema that's set in stone, this isn't a problem.

Something like

```
db.inventory.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $set: { "Easter_2016": "y" } }
)
```

Could add the "Easter_2016" field to a single inventory item without affecting any of the others.  In MySQL, you affect every row in a table by adding a single column --- not so in MongoDB.  Additionally, when querying Mongo, you can search all records (documents) for a field that MAY or MAY not exist.  In MySQL, the field either exists or it doesn't.

MongoDB is built for schemas that are fluid, dynamic, and (potentially) somewhat unknown.  It's speed partially relies on the fact that there aren't monolithic transactions that it may have to undo, and in part that there isn't a schema to constantly validate against when inserting.

Need to analyze 100,000 receipt JSON files from our POS system?  Just run mongoimport and start querying for what you want.

Need to add some special data for just a few inventory items or flag a handful of customers as 'special handing'?  MongoDB for this as well.

Need to import and query tax returns from 20 different states (think:  different field names, different number of fields, with a few overlaps)? Mongo wins here, hands down.

Anything that has several known, concrete steps that MUST work, and work in the proper seqeunce, however (think: ATM machine), and MySQL is a better fit.

Comment: Great answer, although it did not address the second part of my question, the analogy of your example to a travel agency is clear to me, but to continue with your example - where would you draw the line from which it's wiser to use mongo?

Comment: I will edit with a Mongo use case.

Comment: @Daniel the 2nd question is really a design question and it actually depends on a lot of factors, including your personal preferences. I'm still undecided because of this second question, if I should cast a close vote on the question. There are already 2 such votes in the opinion based section. So, I would not really press on with it. JLB provided a really great explanation of what should be in mysql (or any other transaction based rdbms). I think that should suffice for your 2nd question as well.

Comment: @Shadow i guess the 2nd part is indeed opinion based and perhaps was wrong of me to ask, luckily JLB's answer made this question worthwhile and surely will be helpful to many users who encounter the same dilemma.

Comment: @Daniel this is where the huge arguments can start. Most rdbms' have started to implement features that relax the strict restrictions on data structures. Even mysql has limited xml and in its newer versions json features. You can even tweak the traditional data structures to simulate optional data fields. Whether to use these functionality or use mongodb, is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

A query with multiple joins will be a good example. The main idea behind this point, is in relational DB `m:n` relations are symmetrical, whilst in document-oriented DB, they are not. Since v3.2, MongDB has [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which address this issue to some degree.

The line between *core booking engine* and *representation engine* is drawn by [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). The core part must be consistent, while the client-facing part can be implemented with eventual consistency. A [recommended workaround for lack of atomic transactions](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) in MongoDB should shed some light to this statement.  Alternatively your *core booking* part can use [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) to keep state consistent without transactions.